# configuration.Save() always redirect on login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, config, app-config

i want to modify web.config in asp.net web application.i try this

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        section.ConnectionStrings["WebAPP"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ServerName + ";Initial Catalog=" + DrpDatabase.SelectedValue + ";User ID=" + strUserId + ";Password=" + strPassword + "";
        configuration.Save();
```

it is working fine. but after execution of this code it redirect me back to login page, not on default page.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do some redirection after save? Or did you do some checking in the redirected page? The above code only shows the save part. Please post some more code.

Comment: i want to redirect on default page, but it redirect back to login page every time

Comment: But we didn't see any redirection here

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because when modifying the Web.config the AppPool which runs your ASP.Net app will recycle (restart) so the new configuration gets picked up. Because of the restart you are loosing open sessions (authenticated logins) etc. Because the user now is not authenticated properly anymore the default behaviour is to send the user to the configured login-page.

Comment: but any solution for this problem??

Comment: For a "solution" I need to know more of your use-case or you application workflow in general. In what situation are changing web.config and why? Can you configure the login-page to be the "~" (default page) or does this break other parts of your app?

Comment: i want to change my connection string by selecting different database at login time. and at this time i want to change connection string with selected database.